# Этапы в генераторе словарей python с заранее известным значением

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Как здесь происходит процесс генерации словаря с заранее известным значением:

```
{K:0 for K in 'словарь'}
```

Каким образом строка `словарь` разбивается на ключи?

Comment: можно использовать `dict.fromkeys('словарь', 0)` -> `{'ь': 0, 'с': 0, 'в': 0, 'о': 0, 'л': 0, 'а': 0, 'р': 0}`

Answer (score 2):

В цикле вы перебираете строку `'словарь'`, на каждой итерации получаете символ в значение `K` и им указывается ключ словаря

Answer (score 1):

```
stringClass = 'словарь'
stringClassMethods = dir(stringClass)
print(stringClassMethods)

print(hasattr(stringClass, '__iter__'))
it = stringClass.__iter__()

print(hasattr(it, '__next__'))

for a in range(len(stringClass)):
    print(it.__next__())
```

['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**',..., '**iter**']

True

True

с
л
о
в
а
р
ь

строка является объектом класса str, который содержит метод **iter**
при каждом обращении к строке, вызывается метод **next**, который возвращает следующий элемент строки. После достижения последнего элемента, вызывается исключение StopIteration.